# How to filter list based on custom criteria?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a java list consisting of objects. Most of the objects have common fields and I need to keep just the one object from the list of candidates that have a specific field set. How can I achieve this? Example

```
class A{
  String field1;
  String field2;
  String field3;
  LocalDate dateField;

}
```

With the following values;

```
A first = new A("field1","field2","field3",null);
A second = new A("field1","field2","field3",LocalDate.now());
A third= new A("field1","field2","field3",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));
A forth= new A("4","5","6",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));
A fifth = new A("7","8","9",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));
```

I need to write a method that returns a list consisting of second, forth and fifth. So if field1 field2 and field3 are identical, I need to keep the minimum localdate field. How to achieve this?

Comment: Good question. How do you think this might be achieved? If you can show us how far you've already got we can help you understand it.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding two for loops, comparing on the necessary fields and compute a list of candidates based on first 3 fields. Then find object with minimum date and add that to response list. And at the first for loop check if the first object is not already included in the result list. I'm wondering if there is a better approach

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's not a good match for stack overflow. There are other stack exchange sites that may be of more help. A good question here should include what you've tried and an explanation of what has gone wrong.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your selection criteria is and what you really are trying to do.  If you had a method that does what you are asking, what would javadoc say?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a `List<A>` of objects of type `A`.

It seems want to filter the list, querying it for items `A` that match some requirement.  What kinds of things you want to search when filtering that list isn't very clear.

```
 List<A> items = ...; // setup the items
 List<A> items_filtered = items.stream()
   .filter( x -> x.field1.equals("value") )
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<A> items_filtered_2 = items.stream()
   .filter( x -> !x.field2.equals("other_value") )
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

These filters can be applied to any list, including list that is the result of a previous filter, or you can combine two checks in the same filter.

```
 List<A> fitlered_both = items.stream()
   .filter( x -> x.field1.equals("value") && !x.field2.equals("other_value") )
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A first = new A("field1","field2","field3",null);
    A second = new A("field1","field2","field3",LocalDate.now());
    A third= new A("field1","field2","field3",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));
    A forth= new A("4","5","6",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));
    A fifth = new A("7","8","9",LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3));

    List<A> collect = Stream.of(first, second, third, forth, fifth)
   .collect(
         Collectors.groupingBy(a -> Objects.hash(a.field1, a.field2, a.field3),
                    Collectors.minBy((o1, o2) -> {
                        if(o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.dateField == null || o2.dateField == null){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return o1.dateField.compareTo(o2.dateField);
                    })))
            .values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

You want to group the objects by similar objects first, `Objects.hash(field1, field2, field3)` will group objects based on `field1`, `field2`, and `field3`.

Next you want to sort the grouping using `Localdate`.
Next, we collect the first elements of each group, which is our answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to write a comparator and sort the list using it. Then you will be able to retrieve all the desired objects within one pass